# Use create-react-app with a local template?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm developing a cra template, but I can't seem to figure out how to try it out without publishing it to npm. I don't want to publish it until I'm sure it's working. How can I tell cra to use a local template?

Comment: There is a section in the documentation regarding local testing: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates/#testing-a-template

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be to use

`--template file:relative-path-to-template.`

I was omitting the 'file:' part.

Thanks, Christiaan!